# How to deploy on windows server : Kurento one to many broadcast

Tags: javascript, node.js, kurento

**Introduction**

I have cloned the project from this  [git link here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node.git)

App is running on localhost fine.I am willing to deploy this demo project on windows server where it will run on https://localhost:8443. I have no idea how to deploy this specific demo project, although i have successfully deployed another simple node application on iis.

What can be causing problem, i think from script server.js

```
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
var express = require('express');
var minimist = require('minimist');
var ws = require('ws');
var kurento = require('kurento-client');
var fs    = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
    default: {
        as_uri: 'https://localhost:8443/',
        ws_uri: 'ws://93.104.213.28:8888/kurento'
    }
});

var options =
{
  key:  fs.readFileSync('keys/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('keys/server.crt')
};

var app = express();

/*
 * Definition of global variables.
 */
var idCounter = 0;
var candidatesQueue = {};
var kurentoClient = null;
var presenter = null;
var viewers = [];
var noPresenterMessage = 'No active presenter. Try again later...';

/*
 * Server startup
 */
var asUrl = url.parse(argv.as_uri);
var port = asUrl.port;
var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Kurento Tutorial started');
    console.log('Open ' + url.format(asUrl) + ' with a WebRTC capable browser');
});

var wss = new ws.Server({
    server : server,
    path : '/one2many'
}); .....other code
```

I have been trying this for 2 days but no luck.Any expert might help.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you explain what steps you took and what happens when you try to deploy?

Comment: @igracia Thanks for reponse, i deployed this app to "dreamphone.uk/nodeserver", please keep in mind that its windows server and "nodeserver" is actually route to "localhost::8443" . Request is redirected toward localhost successfully and server.js is executed but not entire express application.

Comment: Then you need to an nginx proxy or something similar.